# how to add column mapping in sqlbulkcopy in c# where column names contains White Space

Tags: sql, .net, sqlbulkcopy

```
using (SqlBulkCopy sc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    sc.DestinationTableName = destination;

    sc.ColumnMappings.Add("ID","ID #");
    sc.ColumnMappings.Add("Amount","Amount in USD");

    sc.WriteToServer(datatable);
}
```

I am getting error that column dose not match in given columnmapping

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

found solution need to add Square brackets around the fields only where the White space involved in column name