# SqlBulkCopy fails on columns with spaces in them

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, sqlbulkcopy, columnmappings

I know that I need to wrap any column names with spaces in square brackets `[]`. I do this when I'm building my `DataTable` columns.

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
{
   string colname = columns[i].ToString();

   if (colname.Contains(" "))
   {
      colname = "[" + colname + "]";
   }

   dt.Columns.Add(colname);
}
```

Then, once I've added all of the data as rows in my `DataTable`, I call an insert function, which uses the below code to map the columns. The columns names are identical in both the `DataTable` and the database table.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;
    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

        using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, transaction))
        {
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DBTableName";

            foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
            }

            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint when it is doing the `ColumnMapping`, the `col.ColumName` correctly contains the square brackets around the names with spaces in them.

However when it tries to call the `WriteToServer` method, it fails and the exception says

> The given ColumnName 'Name With Space' does not match up with any column in data source.

Why/where is it stripping out the square brackets, and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the value of brackets is to guard against collision with reserved names. For names with spaces, I wonder if encasing them in quotes (either single or double) would work?

Comment: Try removing the square brackets when adding the ColumnMappings.

Comment: Yeah, not adding the brackets seems to have fixed it. I thought SQL always needed them to deal with the spaces. I had searched and found the below post that confirmed that for me before trying to write my code. Is this just something that newer systems automatically handle correctly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335920/how-to-add-column-mapping-in-sqlbulkcopy-in-c-sharp-where-column-names-contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this has to do with the version of .net or sql server I'm hitting, but I was wrong and didn't need to be adding the square brackets around my column names. It handles the spaces in them correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert all columns then you don't need to have mapping. You can remove this:

```
    foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
    {
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
    }
```

Comment: I am not inserting all columns that are in the database table (nor do I have them in the same order).

Comment: Ah, I can't tell you what's the problem but I can give you workaround. Create one temp or lets say staging table that will have exactly the same structure as your data table. And then do bulk insert there, and after that call stored procedure that will move data from that temp (staging) table to original table.